# How To Make C# Web API Return Values Only, Not Keys

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, serialization, webapi

I am working on a Web API in C#, and would like to return the values only, as opposed to the keys. I am getting the data from a DataSet and so far this is what I have;

```
{
    "Role": [
        {
            "PersonName": "Test, Student1",
            "UserName": "12345",
            "Profile": "STUDENT",
            "Level": "UN",
            "Year": 1,
            "Department": null
        },
        {
            "PersonName": "Test, Student2",
            "UserName": "678910",
            "Profile": "STUDENT",
            "Level": "UN",
            "Year": 1,
            "Department": null
        }, etc
```

What I would like is for the return to look like the below;

```
{
    "Role": [
        {
            "Test, Student1",
            "12345",
            "STUDENT",
            "UN",
            1,
            null
        },
        {
            "Test, Student2",
            "678910",
            "STUDENT",
            "UN",
            1,
            null
        }, etc
```

In my Controller, I am getting the data like so;

```
           List<Roles> studentRoles = new List<Roles>();
           public HttpResponseMessage Get() 
*****some connections here and sql query which I have not included as perhaps irrelevant*****

           sda.Fill(ds, "Role");
            foreach (DataRow drow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                studentRoles.Add(new Roles
                {
                    PersonName = (string)drow["PersonName"],
                    UserName = (string)drow["UserName"],
                    Profile = (string)drow["Profile"],
                    Level = (string)drow["Level"],
                    Year = Convert.ToInt32(drow["Year"]),
                    Department = (drow["Department"] == DBNull.Value) ? "No Department" : drow["Department"].ToString()

                });
            }


            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, ds);
```

Is there a way to ignore the Property Keys (or column names(?)) and return just the Values? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Your expected result is not a valid JSON structure.  Did you mean for `Role` to be an array of arrays (which in turn contain... `dynamic`?  something else?), rather than an array of objects?  What is the actual goal here?

Comment: @David thank you for your reply - the intended goal is for the Web API to be accessible to an external company (once it's completed) and they have specified that they'd like the format to be as I have highlighted in the question. The JSON return I am getting is valid, however they'd like for it to not have the Keys when they send a GET request.

Comment: @GBM What have you created studentRoles  for? you are returning ds.

Comment: @GBM: If what you (they) want is not valid JSON and is instead a custom data format then you'd need to write your own custom logic to produce output of that format.  No built-in serializer is going to do that for you.

Comment: @Serge good spot, I have now removed the Roles class - apologies for that, I shouldn't have included it in the question.

Comment: @David Ah right, so it can only be done by writing our own in-house serializer. Bummer, thought they'd be a way to use NewtonSoft....sigh!

Comment: Sounds like they actually want a row-based format like CSV. I think they'll look at you funny when you send them JSON without property keys instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a bug in your code, you have  created studentRoles but you are returning ds. Fix it and fix the code to something like this

```
    List<List<object>> studentRoles = new List<List<object>>();

    foreach (DataRow drow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        var item = new List<object>();

        item.Add((string)drow["PersonName"]);
        item.Add((string)drow["UserName"]);
        //....
        studentRoles.Add(item);
    };

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { Role= studentRoles });
```

Comment: you are a lifesaver! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much. I have marked your answer as the answer....